# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir varias frases en una oración sin concatenar?

Tags: python, print

Necesito mostrar por consola una variable, una frase, un elemento de una lista y otra variable con formato; necesito que queden en la misma línea, sin embargo me da error.

¿Existe otra manera en que pueda hacer que queden en la misma línea?

Mi código:

```
print((cantidad_uno) + "Leche" + (lista_precios[0]) + ("{0:.2f}".format(subtotal_uno)))
```

El error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Separalos por comas en vez de por `+`. Puedes concatenar cadenas con `+`, pero si no todos los datos son de tipo cadena no te funcionará. También puedes poner `str()` alrededor de cada cosa para convertirlo en cadena y así poder usar el `+`. Y la forma mejor y más flexible es usar cadenas de formato

Answer (score 0):

Como dice abulafia, lo mejor es usar cadenas de formato para no tener que ir transformando números a cadenas y para que sea mucho más legible.

Te pongo algunos ejemplos con tu código para diferentes versiones:

```
#Python 2.7
print('%s Leche %s %0.2f') % (cantidad_uno, lista_precios[0],subtotal_uno) 

#Python 3
print('{} Leche {} {:.2f}'.format(cantidad_uno, lista_precios[0],subtotal_uno)) 

#Python 3.6
print(f'{cantidad_uno} Leche {lista_precios[0]} {subtotal_uno:.2f}')
```